# Unpack a tar without creation of new directories, only merge new files from tar into existing directory structure

Tags: linux, tar

**Situation:**

Lets mention there is a **tar** file with a structure like this:

- DIR A

  - FILE 1
- DIR B

  - FILE 2
- DIR C

  - FILE 3

And on my **disk** there is a directory with a structure like:

- DIR A

  - FILE 1
  - ... *(more files and folders)*
- DIR B

  - ... *(files and folders, but not FILE 2)*

**Question:**

Is there a way to achieve that the unpack command doesn't create new diretories (= directories which are not present in the unpack location shall be skipped/excluded) and that files which are already present won't get replaced?

After unpacking the **disk** structure should be like:

- DIR A

  - FILE 1 *(NOT replaced by tar)*
  - ... *(more files and folders)*
- DIR B

  - FILE 2 *(from tar, because it wasn't there before)*
  - ... *(more files and folders, but not FILE 3)*

*(please note that DIR C should not be created)*

**Update**

I already figured out that '--skip-old-files' achieves that old/existing files will not be replaced at unpacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for d in $(ls -d /home/bob/*/); do tar -x -k -f /tmp/test.tar  ${d}/* ; done
```

where `$(ls -d /home/bob/*/)` list only directories on your destination, -k preserve existing files

Comment: This solution worked for me, I just had to add the -P option to keep the absolute paths. Thanks!